# How to use a VF Page in a Page Layout Section without separating fields

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I have put together a little VF page in order to display a table. I want to use it in a 2 column section within a Page Layout, with fields in the first column and the VF page in the second column. However, when I put the VF Page in the 2nd column it separates the 1st field from the rest by pushing them downwards.

I have included a file to help illustrate what I'm trying to do here :

[image: Page Layout section ; 1st column with fields 2nd with VF page.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal, and, in fact, you can't stop it from happening. Internally, page layouts are rendered as tables, and you can't specify row-spans for a standard layout. You'll want to vote for [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DmM4AAK).

Comment: Thank you - any ideas on a fix for now ? I was thinking of making another VF table for the other 4 fields and just having 2 VF pages in the same section...I'm guessing that would work. If you have any ideas I'd love to hear them.

Comment: @Zoom_v Yes, you could write another VF page. There's just no way to do so with configuration-only.

Answer (score 1):

I would make one VF page consisting of two columns: the left column with the fields now on the left of your page layout section, and the table on the right.  Then place it in a single-column section of the page layout.  That would give you the layout you are looking for, but would mean a little less flexibility for an admin to rearrange fields on the page layout.

Comment: If you want an admin to be able to adjust the fields in the left column, you can use a Field Set.

Comment: just fyi - I ended up making two separate tables dropped into a 2 column section on the page layout. It was easier making two because they ended up being formatted very differently (one had a header, the other didn't). Thank you everybody.